# Spring SseEmitter causes Cannot forward after response has been committed exception

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, server-sent-events, tomcat8

Given a simple controller with a method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "{id}/update")
public ResponseEntity<SseEmitter>  update() throws IOException {
    final SseEmitter  sseEmitter = new SseEmitter();

    return ResponseEntity.ok(sseEmitter);
}
```

I tried it this way also:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "{id}/update")
public SseEmitter  update() throws IOException {
    final SseEmitter  sseEmitter = new SseEmitter();

    return sseEmitter;
}
```

But both way Tomcat 8.0.21 throws the aforementioned exception 30 seconds after the request issued. What is happening under the hood?

Answer (score 3):

This may be the default async timeout of your servlet container.
You can change the default value with Spring:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setDefaultTimeout(1000000);
    }

}
```

Comment: Finally an answer ;) I thought this could be the case but if I cannot set it to forever then it does not solve the problem if you know what I mean. Or there is not a problem at all and on timeout it is acceptable if the server throws an exception like that. However the fact that I cannot write to the emitter after this exception makes me think it is not acceptable.

Comment: The default timeout on tomcat with servlet 3 should be 10 seconds so the connection dropping is normal. I'm not sure how to handle the deconnection gracefully though.
With server-sent events, the client code should handle reconnection automatically and you can include a GUID in your SSE to stream the missed events in case of reconnection.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the timeout for the SseEmitter in its constructor:

```
final SseEmitter sseEmitter = new SseEmitter(60000L); // Timeout in millis
```

The client will reconnect automatically, but by default it will wait 2-3 seconds.
You can override this when you send the messages:

```
// Instruct the client to reconnect after 500ms
emitter.send(SseEmitter.event().reconnectTime(500).data(message));
```

Comment: setting this didn't help much. and in the 7th -8th round stops with error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: ResponseBodyEmitter is already set complete". Why isn't it going for auto retry after 500ms after this exception occurs ? is there any code missing for auto reconnect to work?